# How to use promises for parallel uploads and not be constrained by having to wait for a promise to resolve?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parallel-processing, upload, promise

I'm trying to parallelize uploading files to dropbox and am stuck at the maximum number of parallel requests a browser allows AND those requests needing to finish before the next requests commence. The second part slows things down considerably so I'm wondering if someone has an idea where I'm making things too complicated... Here is the code:

```
...
function DropboxStorage(spec) {
  ...
  if (spec.batch_upload) {
    this._batch_upload = spec.batch_upload;
    this._batch_buffer = parseInt(spec.batch_buffer || 3000, 10);
    this._batch_dict = {"entries": [], "done": [], "defer": {}};
    this._batch_resolver_list = [];
  }
  this._access_token = spec.access_token;
}

// I'm calling putAttachment for both single and batch upload. My idea
// was to use a trigger, which fires after _buffer_batch milliseconds 
// finishing pending items unless resolved "redundant" - rejecting would
// also reject the RSVP.all call. Here is the putAttachment code:

DropboxStorage.prototype.putAttachment = function (id, name, blob) {
  var context = this,
    id = restrictDocumentId(id),
    path;

  restrictAttachmentId(name);
  if (!context._batch_upload) {
     ...
  }

  return new RSVP.Queue()
    .push(function () {
      return jIO.util.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: BATCH_START_URL,
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + context._access_token,
          "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
          "Dropbox-API-Arg": JSON.stringify({"close": false}),
        }
      });
    })
    .push(function (evt) {
      var session_id = JSON.parse(evt.target.response).session_id;
      path = id + "/" + name;
      context._batch_dict.entries.push({
        "cursor": {"session_id": session_id, "offset": blob.size},
        "commit": {
          "path": path,
          "mode": "overwrite",
          "autorename": false,
          "mute": false
        }
      });
      return jIO.util.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: BATCH_UPLOAD_URL,
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + context._access_token,
          "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
          "Dropbox-API-Arg": JSON.stringify({
            "cursor": {"session_id": session_id, "offset": 0},
            "close": true
          })
        },
        data: blob
      });
    })
    .push(function () {
      var len = context._batch_resolver_list.length,
        call_result_defer = new RSVP.defer(),
        trigger = new RSVP.defer(),
        resolver = triggerCancelableBatchResolver(context, trigger.promise);

      // resolve previous call without finishing the batch        
      if (0 < len && len < 1000 &&
        context._batch_dict.entries.length !== 0) {
        context._batch_resolver_list[len - 1].resolve(true);
      }
      context._batch_dict.defer[path] = call_result_defer;
      context._batch_resolver_list.push(trigger);

      // ISSUE: doing the below will parallelize to the max of concurrent
      // requests a browser supports and wait for those to finish
      // return RSVP.all([call_result_defer.promise, resolver]);

      // this works, but without an answer for every request made
      return;
    })
    .push(undefined, function (error) {
      throw error;
    });
};
```

The `triggerCancelableBatchResolver` looks like this:

```
function triggerCancelableBatchResolver(context, trigger) {
  return new RSVP.Queue()

    // wait for 3000ms OR the trigger being resolved
    .push(function () {
      return RSVP.any([RSVP.delay(context._batch_buffer), trigger]);
    })
    .push(function (is_redundant) {
      // trigger => nothing happens
      if (is_redundant) {
        return;
      }
      // finish all pending items
      return new RSVP.Queue()
        .push(function () {
          return jIO.util.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: BATCH_FINISH_URL,
            headers: {
              "Authorization": "Bearer " + context._access_token,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
              "entries": context._batch_dict.entries
            })
          });
        })
        .push(function (evt) {
          context._batch_dict.entries = [];
          context._batch_resolver_list = [];
          return pollForCommitFinish(
           context, JSON.parse(evt.target.response).async_job_id
          );
        })
        .push(function (entries) {
          context._batch_dict.done =  context._batch_dict.done.concat(entries);

          // no more requests coming in, finish
          if (context._batch_dict.entries.length === 0) {
            return finishBatch(context);
          }
        });
    });
}

// recursively loop until commits on Dropbox have completed
function pollForCommitFinish(context, job_id) {
  return new RSVP.Queue()
    .push(function () {
      return jIO.util.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: BATCH_STATUS_URL,
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + context._access_token,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({"async_job_id": job_id})
      });
    })
    .push(function (evt) {
      var status = JSON.parse(evt.target.response);
      if (status['.tag'] === "in_progress") {
        return new RSVP.Queue()
          .push(function () {
            return RSVP.delay(context._batch_buffer);
          })
          .push(function () {
            return pollForCommitFinish(context, job_id);
          });
      }
      return status.entries;
    })
}

// finish the batch returning the correct response for every request
function finishBatch(context) {
  return new RSVP.Queue()
    .push(function () {
      var defers = context._batch_dict.defer;
      return RSVP.all(context._batch_dict.done.map(function (item) {
        var path = item.path_display;
        if (defers[path] === undefined) {
          //throw;
        }
        // return a response to every batch request made
        if (item[".tag"] === "failure") {
          return context._batch_dict.defer[path].reject(item);  
        }
        return context._batch_dict.defer[path].resolve(item);
      }));
    })
    .push(function () {
      context._batch_dict.done = [];
      context._batch_dict.defer = {};
      console.log("DONE")
    });
}
```

The code works, but as mentioned above, if I want to return a response for every request made (or throw in case of issues), I need to return:

```
return RSVP.all([call_result_defer.promise, resolver]);
```

which will stall until `call_result_defer.promise` is resolved at the end of the batch with batch size being limited to number of parallel requests allowed by the browser.

If I instead just

```
return;
```

I can load up to 1000 files into the batch before resolving. However at the cost of being able to return a reply for individual calls to putAttachment.
I have tried returning a promise instead of a defer and calling it's resolve/reject methods once done, but with the same result.

**Question:**
Is there a promise way to return something which "flags" the request as done and returns a result once available? I thought promises where just that, but somehow I cannot get it to work here.

Thanks for help!

Comment: If a browser limits the number of simultaneous connections, then Promises wont change that ... you say `Here is the code` ... I thought you were using promises, but you are not

Comment: yes, but say I can do 8 parallel requests, if I just `return` (see code above),  the browser considers these requests "done" right away and allows the next requests to start. So I'm going 1-1000 without interruptions. If I return the above-mentioned `RSVP.all(...)`, I have to wait until promise 1-8 resolve before requests 9-16 start, then wait for those, etc

Comment: ahhh, I get it now - why not just do all the uploads and let the browser handle the rest

Comment: I can, but as dropbox eventually returns a list of entries with success/failure for every request, I thought I'd try to return the proper response to every request (not using them, so I'll probably just `return`). Still, I was curious if there was a way.

Comment: OH, there is a way - I didn't fully understand the requirements to be honest - not sure if the code in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbcfL9eh/) helps at all

Comment: The question you pose at the end of your post is just wrong.  A promise is merely a notification system allowing you to register an interest in a complete or error notification.  There's no notion of flagging it as "done", but not having a result yet.  That doesn't exist.  It's either done with a result or not.  Besides, the promises themselves have nothing to do with how many simultaneous request you can have.  That's a by-product of how you code and the host browser.